# Связь ComboBox и ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый день, помогите разобраться с проблемкой. 
Есть ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="groupNum"SelectionChanged="groupNum_SelectionChanged">
```

Есть ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="groupSostav" ItemsSource="{Binding}"></ListBox>
```

Есть обработчик события:

```
private void groupNum_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        groupSostav.Items.Clear();

        int n = int.Parse(groupNum.Text);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            groupSostav.Items.Add(n);
        }
    }
```

Выше в конструкторе:

```
if (groupNum.SelectedValue == null)
    {
        groupNum.Text = "5";
    }
```

При выборе значения из CоmboBox в ListBox должно обновляться кол-во полей (Выбрал 9 - стало 9 полей, выбрал 5 - стало 5 и т.д.).

Стартует все это дело нормально, появляется 5 полей в ListBox, далее выбираю к примеру 4 - полей остается 5, далее выбираю 3 - полей становится 4 и т.д., то есть он берет предыдущее значение, подскажите как сделать, чтобы было нормально?

Comment: ` ItemsSource="{Binding}"` - к чему эта связь прицеплена, какой-то список или что?

Comment: Нет, ничего не прицеплено

Comment: а зачем тогда оно? удалите

Comment: Уже, но проблемы это не решило :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        string text = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as string;
        int n = Int32.Parse(text);

        listBox.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(n);
        }

}
```

Бывают ошибки на этапе определения SelectedItem вот несколько вариантов, проверьте какой-то из них должен быть рабочий:

```
string text = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as string;
//string text = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString();

//string text = (e.AddedItems[0] as ComboBoxItem).Content as string;
//string text = ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content as string;
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку: Additional information: Значение не может быть неопределенным.

Comment: @Дмитрий вот вы себя на мое место поставте... Откуда я могу узнать на какой строке возникает ошибка?

Comment: вот в этой string text = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as string;

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/VJ5d3yhv399hAG

Comment: @Дмитрий посмотрите какой из вариантов рабочий, у меня первый, у вас может быть другой.

Comment: 3 и 4 работают, спасибо огромное, а в чем была проблема? В смысле как называется действие которое вы сделали, хочу почитать литературу.

Comment: @Дмитрий смешно, но у меня варианты 3 и 4 нерабочие и вызывают ту же ошибку, а вариант 1 - рабочий. Операция простая: параметр `sender` содержит ссылку на тот объект у которого случилось событие `SelectionChanged`, т.е. мы должны сделать unboxing в `ComboBox`, затем у него определить выбранный элемент - это `SelectedItem`, а потом получить текстовое содержимое, здесь по-идее нужно дергать `Content`, а уже его преобразовывать в строку, но работает и `.ToString()`.

Comment: @Дмитрий по документации мелкомягких `e.AddedItems[0]` должен содержать выбранный элемент, т.е. тот же `SelectedItem`